# Why is the mitzvah called "Shiluach haken"?

Tags: words, mitzvah, language, shiluach-haken

Why is the mitzvah of sending away the mother bird before taking the young called שילוח הקן (Shiluach haken; "sending the nest")? It's not the nest you send away; it's the mother bird. I would have called the mitzvah something like שילוח הציפור (sending the bird) since that's what one does. Alternatively, שילוח האם (sending the mother) matches the language from the [Torah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0522.htm#7): "שַׁלֵּחַ תְּשַׁלַּח אֶת-הָאֵם".

So why is the mitzvah called shiluach haken?

Answer (score 5):

R. Yeruham Fischel Perla ([Negative commandments, §137](https://www.sefaria.org/Commentary_on_Sefer_Hamitzvot_of_Rasag,_Negative_Commandments.136-137?lang=bi)) explains that since it is forbidden to take any of the birds until the mother is sent away the term "שילוח הקן" implies *sending* [of the mother permitting] the *nest*. As he writes:

> והיינו דקרי למצוה זו שילוח הקן. כלומר שילוח שמתיר את הקן.

Or, "nest" can refer to the eggs (cf. [Rashi BM 102a](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%90), s.v. קרי) hence the translation could be: *sending* [of the mother permitting] the *eggs*.